# How to fix printing page error in Laravel

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, printing, bootstrap-4

I added a print button in my blade and it keeps redirecting me to the same view, getting this errors when inspecting 
[image]
and here is my blade :

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery.printPage.js') }}"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <br><br>
        <a href="{{ url('enfants/show/'.$enfant ->id) }}" class="btnprn btn">Print Preview</a></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.btnprn').printPage();
        });

    </script>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the [path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVpHf.png)

Comment: As you can see on your console, `printPage` isn't defined. So I think you have an issue to load your asset. Are you sure that `src="{{ asset('js/jquery.printPage.js') }}"` return a correct path ? (and if you call this URL, do you receive the plugin ?)

Comment: I think you are not able to load any of your scripts, fix that first.